# nodejs - file content as a normal executable code

Tags: node.js

I wonder if I can somehow read file as a code, let me explain.

I'm using 3 different scripts in nodejs, every script contain objects with array

```
config = {};
config.username = 'login';
config.password = 'password';
configsArray.push(config);

config = {};
config.username = 'login2';
config.password = 'password2';
configsArray.push(config);

config = {};
config.username = 'login3';
config.password = 'password3';
configsArray.push(config);
```

sometimes, I adding new accounts to my array, and I need to copy+paste them in every file (script 2x more times), is there any way to read 1 file with these accounts (for example with fs) as a code? so I can put 1 line of code and do my configArray inside one file? (instead of copying it to all files)

Comment: Are you familiar with [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require)? It's the same as importing a builtin module, except you start the string name with `./`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many src files as you want, and you can "insert" the parts each file exports into any other file. I recommend you to have a file per configuration type and then just use them as needed.
For example:

user.js

```
module.exports = { 
  name: 'joe',
  password: '123abc'
}
```

server.js

```
module.exports = { 
  'api-key': 'afafanfanfa',
  admin: 'admin@example.com'
}
```

index.js

```
const serverConfig = require('./server')
const userConfig = require('./user')
console.log('user name', userConfig.name)
console.log('server admin', serverConfig.admin)

// ... etc
```

Comment: Why it does not work ? The script is not really well written, but it should more or less work. What are you getting from this line: `    console.log('Number of configurations set up: ' + configsArray.length);` It should show `Number of configurations set up: 2`